# Como carregar uma imagem em um input type img recebendo a url de outro input

Tags: jquery, imagem, formulário

Boa noite.

Eu tenho um formulário que possui um input que recebe uma url por ajax.

Como eu posso pegar essa url e preencher outro input para visualizar a imagem ?

JS (**aqui passo o id do input que vai receber a url**):

```
$("#thumb").val(json.items[0].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail);
```

INPUT 1 (**aqui o input é preenchido com a url que irei salvar**):

```
<input type="text" id="thumb" value="http://books.google.com/books/content?id=-2DSc30QWpEC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"  />
```

INPUT 2 (**Aqui eu gostaria de mostrar a imagem e não consigo**):

```
<input type="image" src="" id="thumb2" >
```

É possível?

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem o que a senhora deseja fazer. Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: não existe input type="img"... não seria input type="image"?

Comment: @lffg tipo no primeiro input eu recebo a URL pra salvar no meu banco. Esse input não vai aparecer para o usuário. No segundo input eu queria mostrar a imagem .

Comment: @dvd já corrigi. Desculpe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que inserir a imagem no `src` do `input` `#thumb2` pegando o `value` do `input` `#thumb`, após o retorno do Ajax no `:success`:

```
<script>
...ajax
success: function() {
    $("#thumb2").attr("src",$("#thumb").val());
}
</script>
```

Inputs do tipo `image` precisam ter um `src` de onde vão puxar uma imagem, que será o conteúdo do elemento.

[Mais informações nessa documentação do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image).

Comment: fiz as modificações que você passou e mesmo assim ainda não preenche. Coloquei essa sua sugestão $("#thumb2").attr("src",$("#thumb").val()); e não funcionou.

Comment: @AmandaRJ coloque `$("#thumb2").attr("src",$("#thumb").val());` somente após o retorno do Ajax.

Comment: @AmandaRJ Isso quando o input `thumb` já estiver com valor preenchido.

Comment: @AmandaRJ, se você está recebendo uma imagem via AJAX, você deve passar um parâmetro para a função `success`, dessa forma: `success: function(linkImage) {` e substituir `$("#thumb").val()` por `linkImage`. Caso você esteja utilizando um objeto/array, é necessário colocar o caminho completo, ex: `linkImage.thumbnail.src`.

Comment: @dvd, já tinha feito isso que você disse. Só consegui fazer funcionar usando isso: <img src=""  id="thumb2" alt="">  . Obrigada, funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: @AmandaRJ legal. Dei +1 na sua pergunta.